# How to get strtotime() with written time format?

Tags: php, timestamp, strtotime

I need to input, `09 hours 20 minutes` to strtotime and to get the corresponding timestamp. I tried out, `strtotime("09 hours 20 minutes",0)` but it gives me time passed in seconds in current day only. ie `33600`.

I need to get the exact timestamp. ie time passed in seconds from `1-1-1970` to current day `09:20`. Is there anyway? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried adding the timestamp of `00:00 midnight` of "today"?

Comment: I tried `strtotime("09 hours 20 minutes",0)`. I m trying to get rid of  `:` separater  of time in `strtotime`.

Comment: `"09 hours 20 minutes"` since when? today midnight?

Comment: I need to get since `1-1-1970`, but `strtotime("09 hours 20 minutes",0)` gives it from today midnight `12:00am` only.

Comment: or even `strtotime("09 hours 20 minutes", strtotime("today"));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Wong said in the first comment:
use "today" as offset

```
strtotime("09 hours 20 minutes", strtotime("today"));
```